# How to setup typescript + maven eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, eclipse-plugin, typescript

I need to use Eclipse with the Maven plugin. I want to use Typescript with the Typescript(Typecs) plugin. The Typescript plugin does work but the error markers in the Editor disappear after a second. It seems that the Maven plugin and the Typescript plugin do not work togegther well. Has somebody an idea how I can solve this Problem?

Comment: Have you tried Eclipse Wild Web Developer instead? https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the [Palantir Eclipse plugin for TypeScript](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript), you must install node.js in order to use it. But it has nothing to do with Maven.

- It does autocompletion
- Simple refactoring (renaming, ...)
- Navigation
- Automatically builds the .js files after you save a .ts file

Helps a lot.